# Jquery - How do you manage the HTML code?

Tags: jquery, html, templates

for example

**- easy to read**

```
<div class="display">

   <div align="right" bgcolor="fuchia" id="pretendmenu">
        <a href="" class="2">HOME</a> 
        <a href="" class="2">CONTACT</a>
        <a href="" class="2">ABOUT</a>
   </div>

   <div align="left" bgcolor="white" id="content">
      <h5>Content Articles</h5>
      <p>This paragraph would readable material.</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

**- hard to read**

```
$('body').append('<div class="display"> <div align="right" bgcolor="fuchia" id="pretendmenu"> <a href="" class="2">HOME</a> <a href="" class="2">CONTACT</a> <a href="" class="2">ABOUT</a> </div> <div align="left" bgcolor="white" id="content"> <h5>Content Articles</h5> <p>This paragraph would readable material.</p> </div> </div>');
```

**How do you manage the HTML code?**

edit: Maybe with a template system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the [jQuery tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/) templates before with some success.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to put your HTML code in a HTML file, and fetch it back with AJAX, so that the content can be separated from your JavaScript file (easier to maintain).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does have it's own templating system but I've not looked into it in much detail.

You could argue that the readibility of code is of benefit to the developer, but removal of whitespace is beneficial to the end user (via reduced file sizes).
With this in mind you could lay you html out in JS in an indented manner so you can read it sensible, but output it in one line for the end user to improve performance of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You could resort to client templating. You basicly define a template and use jquery to merge your results with it. Data can be fetched from the server via Ajax.

Take a look at the following link for more information about this:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Oct/13/Client-Templating-with-jQuery

Answer (score 0):

[MicroJS](http://microjs.com/#templating) links to some great templating libraries. I really like [ICanHaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/). If you're interested in using CoffeeScript, then I'd recommend also checking out [CoffeeKup](http://coffeekup.org/).